# uitableview's index is shrinking

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have an app very similar to address book of iphone. The entire search and index stuff is implemented using the searchdisplay controller. The problem is, from the search results when i click some cell, it actually loads a new screen and while pressing back and going to home tableview screen the index is shrinks

The possible reason which I could think is the keyboard. Is there way to make auto resizing of the index on the right side of the uitableview even after the keyboard appears for searchbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the problem in my source code. I actually release the keyboard when i am loading the view from the search results. when i come back from the newly loaded view and press the standard cancel button it loaded the tableview with half index view. Now i deleted the code which actually releases the keyboard. Then it worked normally.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean resize the index to the full length of the table after you have removed the keyboard for the search has gone?  If so, use can `reloadSectionIndexTitles`.

Comment: i tried that . . .no luck . . i put that in viewWillLoad method and tried. No luck on simulator 3.1 and device 3.1.2 . .and also on iphone 4.0.

Comment: wow i fixed the problem. The mistake which i did is this. When i jump from my search results to new view i was actually releasing the searchbar's keyboard. I now left it just like that and its working.